# tinyMce drag and drop issue with text

Tags: tinymce

When using tinyMce, I want to be able to drop and drop paragaphs of text using the usual drag and drop code

```
    function allowDrop(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
    
       ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {

      ev.preventDefault();
      var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
     ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
```

However, when I drop into tinyMcs, it drops the **span's ID name** not the content of the span itself, while  it works fine when dropping into a regular DIV.

Does the drop event need to work differently?

Answer (score 1):

The lovely people at TinyMCE answered my issue, by setting up an event handler within the tinyMCE intitate statement by adding this bit of code setup: (editor) => {
editor.on('drop', drop);
}, While it doesnt allow you to drag the element back out again, it achived what I needed.

```
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea",
plugins: [
    "help", "image", "insertdatetime", "link", "lists", "media", 
 ],
setup: (editor) => {
  editor.on('drop', drop);
},
toolbar: "undo redo | styles | bold italic underline strikethrough"});
```

Comment: This is a great generic technique for hacking into arbitrary MCE events.